# Get position of raycast even when it doesn't hit anything

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a simple building system and here's a small gif of what I've got. Right now the preview object disappears when raycast doesn't hit anything. I want it to change it's Y position when I look up but then the raycast doesn't return anything, how would I achieve that?

https://gfycat.com/ifr/ShallowTepidAnkolewatusi

Here's the bit of code that's responsible for preview position

```
        if (deployPreview)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward, out deployableHit, 5, deployableMask))
            {
                if (deployPreview.gameObject.activeSelf)
                {
                    if (deployableHit.transform != transform)
                    {
                        if (heldDeployable.deployable.DepType == EDeployableType.Buildable)
                        {
                            HandleBuilding();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            deployPos = deployableHit.point;
                            deployPreview.rotation = transform.rotation;
                            deployPreview.position = deployPos;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the position where ray ends and move your preview object there.

```
if (deployPreview)
{
        if (Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward, out deployableHit, 5, deployableMask))
        {
           //your code
        }
        else
        {
           //not hit code
           var position = cam.position + cam.forward * 5;
           //position is where ray ends
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.